# Cloudant search query to search from variable

Tags: java, lucene, websphere, cloudant

I have the following in cloudant database

```
`{
  "_id": "72b48c107bda43827bcfba8761f00cf4",
  "_rev": "1-2c4246347f215ef82f4372659249c412",
  "delivery_id": 321,
  "purchase_item": "Paint"
 }`

`{
  "_id": "72b48c107bda43827bcfba8761f00cf4",
  "_rev": "1-2c4246347f215ef82f4372659249c412",
  "delivery_id": 528,
  "purchase_item": "Glass"
 }`
```

I have the following index :

```
`function (doc) {
   index("deliveryid", doc.delivery_id,  {"store":true});
   index("purchaseitem", doc.purchase_item,  {"store":true});
 }`
```

I want to search using deliveryid but the value is coming from  a variable. Like,
`value = 321`

How can I use the "value" in below search query ?
`query = "_design/app/_search/_delivery_id/?query=deliveryid"`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're building up the URL string, so concatenate your variable to the query (noting the `name:value` Lucene syntax)

```java
query = "_design/app/_search/_delivery_id/?query=deliveryid:" + value
```